# ¿Por qué no me muestra los resultados mi programa?

Tags: c

Este es mi programa que compila sin error, sin embargo no me muestra resultados. ¿por qué?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define PI 3.14159265359 
#include<math.h>

double a, w, g, T, f, k, v, am, vm, y, i, im, yi;

int main(void)
{
    printf("Ingresar la amplitud de la onda:");
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    printf("Ingresar la velocidad angular de la onda en radianes / segundo:");
    scanf("%lf",&w);
    printf("Ingresar la fase inicial de la onda en radianes:");
    scanf("%lf",&g);

    v= (a*w)/(2*PI);

    T=a/v;

    f=1/T;

    k= (2*PI)/a;

    vm=-a*w;

    am=-a*(pow (w,2));

    i=0;

    im=0;

    yi=0;

    while (i<=60);
    { 
       i=i+1;

       y= a*(sin((2*PI*f*i)+g));

       if (y>yi)

       {
          yi=y;
          im=i;

       } 
       else
       {
          yi=yi;
          im=im;
       }
     }          

     printf("\nEl valor maximo de la funcion es %e \n",yi);  
     printf("\nEncontrado en el segundo %e \n",im);
     printf("\nCon una frecuencia en Hertz de %e \n",f);
     printf("\nCon un periodo de %e \n",T);
     printf("\nVelocidad de propagacion en m/s %e \n",v);
     printf("\nCon un numero de ondas %e \n",k);
     printf("\nCon una velocidad maxima %e \n",vm);
     printf("\ny una aceleracion maxima %e \n",am);

     getch();

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4):

```
while (i<=60);
//           ^ ese punto y coma
```

Ese caracter que te indico hace que el `while` **no ejecute nada**. Con nada me refiero a que se queda en un bucle sin fin, ya que **siempre** se va a cumplir que `i<=60`. El bucle se repetirá indefinidamente hasta que te aburras y mates el programa o tu madre le pegue una patada a tu ordenador para que deje de consumir energía sin sentido.

Se puede ver más claro así (el código es equivalente)

```
while(i<=60)
{ }

{
  i=i+1;

  y= a*(sin((2*PI*f*i)+g));

  // ...
}
```

La solución es tan sencilla como eliminar ese punto y coma.